# Firebase Signin with Email Link Removes a Path In ActionCodeSettings URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried using the firebase sign in with email link as follows:

```
firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(input.userDetails.user_email, {
    url: 'https://mydomain/register/complete-registration',
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
        bundleId: 'myIOSBundle'
    },
    android: {
        packageName: 'myAndroidAppId',
            installApp: true,
            minimumVersion: '12'
        },
    dynamicLinkDomain: 'myDynamicLinkDomain'
})
```

I receive the email as expected, but when I click on the **sign in** button from my email, my actionCodeSettings URL changes from *https://mydomain/register/complete-registration* to *https://mydomain/complete-registration?apiKey=API_KEY&oobCode=CODE&mode=signIn&lang=en*. Why is firebase removing the **'register'** from my url path?